# Problems with classes (super new)

Tags: class, new-operator, smalltalk, super

I've problems to figure it out what's happening in the following exercise, I'm learning Smalltalk, so I'm newbie.

Class A>>new
  ^super new initialize.

A>>initialize
  a:=0.

Class B>>new: aParameter
  |instance|
  instance := super new.
  instance b: instance a + aParameter.
  ^instance

B>>initialize
  b:=0.

The problem says what happen when the following code is executed:

B new:10.

But I can't not figure it out why instance variable does not belong to A class.

Thanks

Comment: What are you seeing that's unexpected? Are you getting an error? I don't understand your last sentence. Which instance variable does not belong to A (or A class?) that should?

Comment: When I execute the code (B new:10.) I get an error saying that the + method is not defined, and the class of instance variable is B, not A (the super class of B), that's why I'm confused.

To be more clean, I don't know why when the code executes:

instance := super new.

The class of instance variable is B, and I can't execute the next step.

Comment: +1 for finding and fixing your own problem.

Answer (score 3):

I discovered the issue, the missing of super initialize, when the code was executed the initializer of "instance := super new." was the initializer of class B, that's why the A instance var was not initialized, the following code fix the issue:

B>>initialize

super initialize.

b:=0.

Comment: I'd noticed that, but sometimes that's exactly what you want. Glad to hear you sorted out your problem!